# how can I avoid getting generate one vcard instead of given ones?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a vcards from a given template, but it only generates the last one. however, I want to add each time a new template-based my database phones, but I am not sure why I am getting only one `id` , and the last phone only. it should be getting 91 contacts plus its id

```py
def generate():
    import os
    _id = 0
    while _id < 91:
        phone = open('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\phone', 'r').read().splitlines()
        for idx in phone:
            template = open('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\client.vcf','r')
            final = open('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\final.vcf','w')
            template = template.read()
            template = template.replace("CLIENT","CLIENT {}".format(_id))
            template = template.replace("PHONE", idx)
            final.write(template)
        _id += 1
```

I am getting the output of this template

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:;CLIENT 90;;;
FN:CLIENT 90
TEL;TYPE=CELL;TYPE=pref;TYPE=VOICE:1111111111
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iCloud Web Address Book 1923B15//EN
REV:2020-01-03T19:21:22Z
END:VCARD
```

I want to have this output

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:;CLIENT 1;;;
FN:CLIENT 1
TEL;TYPE=CELL;TYPE=pref;TYPE=VOICE:111111111
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iCloud Web Address Book 1923B15//EN
REV:2020-01-03T19:21:22Z
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:;CLIENT 2;;;
FN:CLIENT 2
TEL;TYPE=CELL;TYPE=pref;TYPE=VOICE:222222222222
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iCloud Web Address Book 1923B15//EN
REV:2020-01-03T19:21:22Z
END:VCARD
```

Comment: Move the two `open` lines before the `while` loop

Comment: You're only getting the last one written because you have the `open('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\final.vcf','w')` inside the `for` loop, so it re-writes the file every iteration and wipes out anything that was put in it previously. Move **it** to just before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you describe is because you keep opening your output file with 'w' which will overwrite the file if it exists - take a look at [Python - Files I/O](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)
.

Either open the file with 'a' or just open it once and use it for the entire loop.

Try this (still bad code but reduces unnecessary opens):

```
import os
def generate():
    phone = open('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\phone', 'r').read().splitlines()
    template = open('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\client.vcf','r').read()
    final = open('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\final.vcf','w')

    for _id in range(91):
        for idx in phone:
            final.write(template.replace("CLIENT","CLIENT {}".format(_id)).replace("PHONE", idx))
```

Comment: why does it always overwriting the same file?

Comment: Because you open the file with `'w'` mode. Take a look at the link in my answer.